how to make yarn workspaces install package.json located in packages sub folder?
I have a folder structure like this:
root/
  packages/
    snackbar/
      src/
      example/
        src/
        babel.config.js
        metro.config.js
        package.json
      tsconfig.json
      package.json
  .yarnrc.yml
  package.json

with this setup for .yarnrc.yml and package.json
.yarnrc.yml:
nodeLinker: node-modules
nmHoistingLimits: workspaces

plugins:
  - path: .yarn/plugins/@yarnpkg/plugin-interactive-tools.cjs
    spec: "@yarnpkg/plugin-interactive-tools"
  - path: .yarn/plugins/@yarnpkg/plugin-workspace-tools.cjs
    spec: "@yarnpkg/plugin-workspace-tools"

yarnPath: .yarn/releases/yarn-3.6.1.cjs

package.json:
{
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "packageManager": "yarn@3.6.1",
  "private": true,
  {other property like dependencies, devDependencies, scripts, etc}
}

whenever I run yarn install from root folder, yarn didn't add node_modules folder at root/packages/snackbar/example. How do i tell yarn to add/install node_modules into root/packages/snackbar/example too when I run yarn install?

You have declared root/packages/snackbar as a workspace but not root/packages/snackbar/example. You have to edit root/package.json or root/packages/snackbar/package.json to include root/packages/snackbar/example as a workspace.
